# Getting started with databases

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, mongodb, ember.js, database

I am currently a front end developer. I know HTML and CSS pretty well, I'm OK with jQuery and know some Vanilla JS. I have an idea for a website I want to create where I will be storing data for products (data that I will be grabbing from various websites around the web). It's basically a help me choose application where the user will go through some steps and be given some choices based on their selections. This site is nothing new, but it's more for learning purposes/portfolio work.

Most of my co-workers use ASP.NET and I've seen that you can setup a website like this using ASP.NET and the provided server controls along with C#, however, I want to take another route that allows me to do the same thing NOT using ASP.NET (C# is OK and preferred if that is possible) in that I can grab data, store data, and bind data to my page.

In addition to this, I would like to do this on the Mac.

Here's a list of things I have looked at:

- MongoDB (I was really confused by the setup and didn't read anywhere that this would definitely be the solution).
- AngularJS
- EmberJS
- BackboneJS
- Several other JS frameworks
- Ruby on Rails

**Note about the above:** Some of the above might be the solution, but I don't want to start spending time learning them only to realize a week in that this is not going to help me get to my goal.

If this post would be better suited for another stack site please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Look at [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a basic website with a persistence you'll need to deal with three parts the front-end (client), back-end (server) and the persistence (database). Of the things that you've listed Angular, Ember and Backbone are all front-end frameworks. They each have their own way of approaching the issue but they all work in the client facing part of the project so views, interaction and dispatching data to the backend. Rails is the only thing that you've listed that's a back-end framework, another option for the back-end if you're more familiar with JS might be Node and Express. Node allows you to build a server in JS and Express is one of the more popular Node frameworks. That section will be responsible for getting the calls for data and calls with data from the front-end and dispatching the appropriate response. Rails typically works with with a SQL database like MySQL or PostGres out of the box because Rails' active record is meant to work with SQL. Mongo is a NoSQL database and I think people are getting it working with Rails but I don't know that it's highly common. Mongo's shell is pretty much javascript and it stores data as JSON (not technically but close enough) so it's been a comfortable choice for JS developers learning back-end. Either Rails or Node can get a server up and running locally on your machine so you can work with the full architecture. So what it comes down to really is picking one of each from those sections and making them play nicely together. For your purposes I would think that the way to go would be either a basic Rails app (probably with MySQL) and using jQuery ajax calls to manage some calls from the front-end or building something with the so-called MEAN stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) which is all JS and using Angulars built in http functionality to handle those calls. Hope this at least narrowed the field of research a bit. Really thats a pretty open question and there are a lot of options.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of details I was looking for. I realize it was open ended, but I appreciate you taking the time to answer.

I'm glad I didn't go further into any of those front-end frameworks (for now). The Node.js w/Express route does interest me, but in terms of long term growth with experience in that -- would you say it's worth learning? 

I will definitely look into the MEAN stack as well.

You have definitely narrowed the field down for me and I at least know where to go next without wasting too much time.

Answer (score 0):

What is your webhosting site? I suggest`Phpmyadmin` Or `Mysqldatabase` You can create tables and strings where you can put the websites you wanna "grab" data from and put a little javascript in there to tell your website `if blahblahnlah =blahblahblah then get id="website1"`

Answer (score 0):

Some clarifications:

- At first, you need to distinguish between a server side language (used to program the functionality) and a database (used to store data).
- C# is a language of the .net framework. Regarding websites, there's no C# without ASP.net.
- There are two major groups for realizing back end solutions: PHP (market share ~ 40%) and ASP (~ 25%). PHP is a programming language, ASP.net incorporates several programming languages (mainly C# and  VB.net).
- Both worlds are able to connect to databases: For PHP, this is mainly MySQL, for ASP.net it is mostly Microsoft SQL server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It gives me a better understanding into what languages I should be looking at. Any thoughts on Node.js?

Comment: "Thoughts" (as opposed to "facts"): node.js is a "cool thing", but I would not suggest it for a beginner. Many things are just provided out-of-the-box by ASP.net (or, not so comfy, by PHP), you do not have that comfort in node.js, thus you'll learn the hard way and will simply need longer to fulfill a task/get a website running/etc.. I would suggest to simply grab a book about ASP.net MVC, it's my personal jack of all trades in server side programming.